# Overflow hidden not working after putting it in the parent element for my NAV

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i am trying to translate the nav links during small devices and it works however it is scrolling sideways and the overflow hidden for the parent element is not working i thought it will crop the element if it is placed on the right of the screen. any suggestions

```js
const navSlide=()=>{
    const burger= document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav= document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks= document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li')


    //toggle nav
    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //animate links
        navLinks.forEach((link,index)=>{
            if(link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation= '';
            }
            else{
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index/7 +0}s`;
            }
        });
        //burger animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });


}
navSlide();
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    nav{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items:center;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        height: 84vh;
        width: 100%;
        top:15vh;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #f44336;
        z-index: 5;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .nav-links li a{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-active{
        transform:translateX(0%);
    }
    @keyframes navLinkFade {
        from{
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(50px);
        }
        to{
            transform: translateX(0px);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .toggle .line1{
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
    }
    .toggle .line2{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .toggle .line3{
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);        
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="./index.html"><img src="./Images/Screenshot_2022-08-14_230341-removebg.png"/></a>
      <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a>About</a></li>
          <li><a>Work</a></li>
          <li><a>Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

  <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```